Hi, Is there any algorithm that use rough set theory for dimensionality reduction using python or matlab?
I tried using the python codes from this website https://github.com/paudan/scikit-roughsets/blob/master/scikit_roughsets/roughsets.py, unfortunately i am not getting any results. I am facing error.
Do anyone having experience in using rough set theory for dimensional reduction on a dataset using either python or matlab? If there is any, please share here. Thank you.
Trying to get help on coding part using python or matlab.
